# What does "raise holy hell" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "raise holy hell" mean? Is it a common phrase to use? I Googled the phrase, but couldn't find any definition.

It is used in the following context:

> In the end it was Stanley Stewart, from the family's third generation, who *raised holy hell* (including knocking over a table during a heated argument) and finally convinced the family to move ahead with its own branding campaign.

Comment: In the UK I think people say *"raise **merry** hell"* more often.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Neither are a particularly common expression in the UK, but yes, *raise merry hell* is used a bit more. We're more likely to talk about creating chaos or mayhem.

Comment: @Lunivore: If by that you mean you think they're both more common in America, I disagree. Here's my evidence that [holy hell](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=merry+hell%2Choly+hell&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) has recently shot to prominence in the US, whereas [merry hell](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=merry+hell%2Choly+hell&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) has always been the UK's preference. And the "prevalence" figures suggest the "merry" version actually occurs *more often* in the UK, per million words in print.

Comment: I have no idea whether they're common in America; just saying it's not an expression I really hear in the UK, though I do read it in older books. I'm in the UK and couldn't possibly comment on the US. It is entirely possible that it's *more common* in the UK, just saying that *more common* doesn't mean *common*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to create havoc or chaos, usually in a confrontational or argumentative way.

If you search for *raise hell* you'll find the definition you're looking for - [here's one](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/raise+hell). The word *holy* is just there as emphasis. I particularly like the way in which *holy* and *hell* used together - being opposites - show the breadth of the chaos that *holy hell* will create.

Comment: Ah, that was why I couldn't find any definition... :S thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**To raise / create**: Holy Hell; Merry Hell; All Hell; Hell on Earth; a Hell of a Stink, were widely used expressions in UK English as recently as the late 20th Century.
The use of 'religious' references [ Holy; Hell; Jesus;  etc] in UK English as curses has a long history with words such as 'Zounds' = HIS wounds / Jesus' wounds, being common in Shakespearian and subsequent times. This use has declined rapidly with the decline in perceived fear of divine power and retribution.
A similar softer cursing - ruddy = bloody; heck = hell has also fallen into non-use.
Modern UK cursing, swearing and personal abuse now focuses on, for example: sexual references utilizing the short Anglo Saxon words for sexual [Female] parts, and the act of copulation.